# C++ to android shared library with Android-NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am trying to get a unity native audio plugin to run on android, I have a .bundle complied by xcode that runs on osx.

My steps for attempting to get the .so needed for android is having the two following mk files in the project folder :

Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_MODULE := AudioPluginDemo
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/%=%)
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am expecting this file to set LOCAL_PATH to the project folder, find a list of all cpp files in src, all files in include and then build a .so with them.

Application.mk

```
APP_OPTIM        := release
APP_ABI          := all
APP_PLATFORM     := android-17
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
APP_STL          := gnustl_static
```

and then running with :

```
ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=<PATH_TO_APPLICATION.MK>
```

this appears to run fine, creating all the .so files. However they are small in size (6kb) and when running on unity android the plugins are not found. Peeking into them with nm -D also does not give me the expected symbols. I have a feeling that I am not telling ndk-build to look in the right locations for the source files, (ndk-build -d to debug shows a lot of references to the NDK path, but none to the project folder) but can not work out why.

Comment: `ndk-build V=1` will show you all the commands it's running. Make sure those match what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, NDK_PROJECT_PATH was defaulting into the NDK root directory, instead of my project. Added an extra argument when calling the ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=<PATH_TO_PROJECT>

So it builds now (it crashes on load in unity Android, but it builds!)